# Problems with the video player sample from Android Developers...¿how to specify the path of the video?

Tags: android, video, mp4

i'm trying to play a video with the sample of Video Player from Android developers: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html

I have a mp4 video (1.mp4) stored on the assets folder, but i dont know how to specify the path variable to point into that file

THis is the code i have:

```
public class DemoVideoActivity extends Activity {

/**
 * TODO: Set the path variable to a streaming video URL or a local media
 * file path.
 */
private String path = "";
private VideoView mVideoView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

    if (path == "") {
        // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
        Toast.makeText(
                DemoVideoActivity.this,
                "Please edit VideoViewDemo Activity, and set path"
                        + " variable to your media file URL/path",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        /*
         * Alternatively,for streaming media you can use
         * mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring));
         */
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, This is solution for video from **/res/raw** folder, (Actually I got it from somewhere in SO and it works in my case)

1. Copy the video into your project's **res/raw** folder.
2. Video file must be in a supported format (3gp, wmv, mp4 ).
3. Make reference through the generated R statics - it will have the file extension removed: **R.raw.my_video_file**

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView)
String uri = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.my_video_file;
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
videoView.start();
```

And video **from asset** I never try that but, If you are use MediaPlayer then I think this will help you,

```
AssetFileDescriptor fileDes = getAssets().openFd(fileName); 
player.setDataSource(fileDes.getFileDescriptor(),fileDes.getStartOffset(), fileDes.getLength());
```

Here player is media player's object.

Thanks.